# Global queue on server side

Tags: django, queue

When users uploading the file to server, their file will be queued and are waiting to process by human.

I've already created SQL table which store name, status and estimate time-consuming of the files.
And I want to create a feature that users can know how many file which come before and how long their file have to wait.

Sometimes there will be file that jumping the queue.

First attempt are using SQL query, but It's a bad practice. (I've do the search [here](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you))

So, Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Like Erik Cederstrand pointed out, RabbitMQ can work with your situation. If you like something to handle background processes I recommend Django-Q or Celery.

Comment: Also, using a database as a queue is a bad idea *if you have a considerable amount of traffic*. If you have less than say 10.000 incoming files per day, then it makes absolutely  no difference what you use. In that case, I would opt for the simple solution and just use the existing database.

Comment: Thanks for your replying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more detail about e.g. performance requirements, data volume, queue prioritisation and what you actually mean by "global", you could use RabbitMQ as a server-side queue to store your messages. It works well with Django projects.

Comment: Celery is not a queueing system it's designed to run background processes, rabbit-mq or redis can both be used a global queues.

Comment: I know. Someone edited my answer to the worse. Editing back now.

Comment: I've add more details, Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Cool thanks for fixing your answer